# Assembly Redirection doesn't seem to get applied

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort out some assembly redirection that I'm having problems with, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working at the moment. I've checked all the standard things (and I've actually generated it from a script that's previously worked) and can't figure out what's wrong. These are my errors:

[image]

While my current setup is:

[image]

I don't want to use the **b.b** version of the DLL's so I've got my app.config for my **Tests.csproj** file setup with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.AmazonStorage" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.370"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.AzureStorage" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.370"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Blogs" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.388"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Chat" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.390"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CKEditor" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.379"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CMSHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.374"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CMSSiteMapProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CMSStorage" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Community" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.388"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Controls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.381"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Controls.XmlSerializers" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.381"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.DatabaseHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.368"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.DataCom" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.394"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.DataEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.DataProviderSQL" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.DocumentEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.372"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Ecommerce" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.390"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.EcommerceProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.393"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.EmailEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.368"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.EventLog" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.EventManager" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.378"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.ExtendedControls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.377"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.FormControls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.385"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.FormEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.370"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Forums" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.387"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.GlobalEventHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.GlobalHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.365"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.ImportExport" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.IO" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.364"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.ISearchEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.363"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.LicenseProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.LicenseProvider.XmlSerializers" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.MediaLibrary" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.387"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.MembershipProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.MessageBoard" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.387"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Messaging" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.377"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.MetaWeblogProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.395"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Newsletter" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Notifications" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.388"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.OnlineMarketing" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.392"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.OutputFilter" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.374"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Polls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.370"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.PortalControls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.384"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.PortalEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.372"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.ProjectManagement" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.378"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Reporting" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.380"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.ResourceManager" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.364"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SalesForce" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.393"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Scheduler" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.371"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SearchProviderSQL" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SettingsProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.363"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SharePoint" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.378"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SiteProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.369"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.skmMenuControl" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.379"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SocialNetworking" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.388"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.Synchronization" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.367"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.SynchronizationEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.TranslationServices" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.374"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.UIControls" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.386"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.URLRewritingEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.377"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.VirtualPathHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.366"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.VirtualPathProvider" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.378"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WebAnalytics" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.371"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WebDAV" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.391"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WebFarmSync" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.367"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WebFarmSyncHelper" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.375"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WebServices" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.376"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WinServiceEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.451"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.WorkflowEngine" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535" newVersion="7.0.4787.371"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.JustMock" publicKeyToken="721b6c5bc0326b3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2014.1.1317.4" newVersion="2014.1.1317.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The scriptcs script that I've used to generate these:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var helper = new AssemblyHelper();
helper.GenerateAssemblyRedirects(@"c:\source\test");

public class AssemblyHelper
{
public void GenerateAssemblyRedirects(String path)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(String filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        String file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        if(filePath.EndsWith(".dll") && file.StartsWith("CMS."))
        {

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(filePath);
            var assemblyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            var assemblyID = Regex.Match(assembly.FullName, "PublicKeyToken=[a-zA-Z0-9]*").Value.Replace("PublicKeyToken=", "");
            var assemblyVersion = Regex.Match(assembly.FullName, @"Version=[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*").Value.Replace("Version=", "");


            sb.AppendLine(@"<dependentAssembly>");
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"<assemblyIdentity name=""{0}"" publicKeyToken=""{1}"" />", assemblyName, assemblyID));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"<bindingRedirect oldVersion=""7.0.0.0-7.0.65535.65535"" newVersion=""{0}""/>", assemblyVersion));
            sb.AppendLine(@"</dependentAssembly>");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have anything to do with assembly direction.  Which is something that only applies at *runtime*.  You have *compile-time* errors.

The compiler is fretting about seeing the wrong version of the reference assembly.  That version was recorded in your project file when you first added the reference, possibly months ago.  But now it is rebuilding the program and the reference assembly is no longer the same version.  You can tell it not to worry about that, select the reference assembly in the References node of your project, set the "Specific version" property to False.

It will now take whatever version it finds without complaint.  Beware of compile errors due to drastic changes in the assembly.  Very high odds that you don't need the assembly redirects in the .config file, so remove them.

Comment: Thanks Hans - I hadn't spotted the blindly obvious compiled error - being silly. However specific version is already set to false both on the Tests.csproj file and the NetC.Mock.dll

Comment: It is complaining about the other reference assemblies, CMS.DataEngine etc, not about NetC.Mock or a test project file.  Not that clear why you added them in the first place, remove them.  Add them back when you get complaints, that in itself fixes the problem.